# Stormpath Perfect-Turnstile Initial Server

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, stormpath, perfect

I'm trying to test iOS server side user-authentication using [Turnstile-Perfect](https://github.com/stormpath/Turnstile-Perfect) (a Stormpath implementation for swift and perfect on the server side) by building out the backend for [Stormpath's iOS client-side notes tutorial](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-note-taking-app-swift-ios) using Perfect and Turnstile-Perfect. While I can get a server up and running for basic requests (see bottom of post), the user auth doesn't work at all, presumably because I am missing the step in setting up the database where I actually create the database structures for storing the auth data. Specifically, when I use Postman to test my server with the following post:

```
{ "givenName": "Testing", "surname": "Tester", "email": "test@example.com", "password": "TestTest1" }
```

I receive the following error:

```
The file /register was not found.
```

How do I build this out? When running Stormpath's node.js implementation, I just run:

```
npm install -g stormpath-spa-dev-server
```

What's the swift Perfect-Turnstile equivalent?

---

Current server code, written in the "main.swift" file in [this project](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git):

```
import PerfectLib
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer
import TurnstilePerfect
import SQLite

// Create HTTP server.
let server = HTTPServer()

// The Turnstile instance
let turnstile = TurnstilePerfect()
server.setRequestFilters([turnstile.requestFilter])
server.setResponseFilters([turnstile.responseFilter])


// Register your own routes and handlers
func getHandler(request: HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse) {
  response.appendBody(string: "get notes")
  response.completed()
}

func postHandler(request: HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse) {
  response.appendBody(string: "post notes")
  response.completed()
}

var routes = Routes()
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/notes", handler: {
  request, response in getHandler(request: request, response: response)
  }
)
routes.add(method: .post, uri: "/notes", handler: {
        request, response in postHandler(request: request, response: response)
  }
)

// Add the routes to the server.
server.addRoutes(routes)

// Set a listen port of 3000
server.serverPort = 3000

// Set a document root.
// This is optional. If you do not want to serve static content then do not set this.
// Setting the document root will automatically add a static file handler for the route /**
server.documentRoot = "./webroot"

// Gather command line options and further configure the server.
// Run the server with --help to see the list of supported arguments.
// Command line arguments will supplant any of the values set above.
configureServer(server)

do {
  // Launch the HTTP server.
  try server.start()
} catch PerfectError.networkError(let err, let msg) {
  print("Network error thrown: \(err) \(msg)")
}
```

Comment: Hey Ethan -- I'm the guy who wrote the tutorial you're using and Turnstile. Even though Turnstile is made by Stormpath, Turnstile doesn't use Stormpath for authentication and is an "independent" authentication framework for server-side Swift, so the tutorial you're working won't work with Turnstile. Turnstile is a set of tools to help you build your own authentication for server-side Swift. I'll write some tutorials on it soon.

Comment: That would be great!